# Mongo DB Canonical address does not match server address

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-data-mongodb

I am connecting my spring boot application with mongo db.

The code is working fine on local environment where the db has a single node and not running in cluster mode.

But when the db is running on staging environment with cluster mode and a single node and 1 replica set, the spring application shows the following error:

```
INFO  |  |  | 2019-04-18 12:43:25 | [cluster-ClusterId{value='5cb823951a734cea7f7eebe1', description='null'}-10.202.41.254:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger - Canonical address educationelasticsearch-digital-v1-41-254:27017 does not match server address.  Removing 10.20.41.254:27017 from client view of cluster
INFO  |  |  | 2019-04-18 12:43:25 | [cluster-ClusterId{value='5cb823951a734cea7f7eebe1', description='null'}-educationelasticsearch-digital-v1-41-254:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server educationelasticsearch-digital-v1-41-254:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: educationelasticsearch-digital-v1-41-254: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) [mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: educationelasticsearch-digital-v1-41-254: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar:?]
    ... 5 more
```

In both the case, application properties are same except the change in IP of staging server in place of localhost:

```
spring.elasticsearch.education.hostname=localhost   // staging server IP
spring.elasticsearch.education.scheme=http
spring.elasticsearch.education.port=9200


###### Mongo properties ########
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost  //staging server ip
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=ddddd
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=root
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41892411/mongodb-hostname-uri-configuration) but not much resolution in this.

Please suggest what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34373673/5712629.

Maybe spring.data.mongodb.host and spring.data.mongodb.port are not supported in this version of mongodb driver.

You could try:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017
```

instead.